# how to loop through string for patterns from linux shell?

Tags: linux, string, bash, awk, split

I have a script that looks through files in a directory for strings like `:tagName:`  which works fine for single `:tag:` but not for multiple `:tagOne:tagTwo:tagThree:` tags.

My current script does:

```
grep -rh -e '^:\S*:$' ~/Documents/wiki/*.mkd ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd | \
sed -r 's|.*(:[Aa-Zz]*:)|\1|g' | \
sort -u
printf '\nNote: this fails to display combined :tagOne:tagTwo:etcTag:\n'
```

The first line is generating an output like this:

```
:politics:violence:
:positivity:
:positivity:somewhat:
:psychology:
:socialServices:family:
:strategy:
:tech:
:therapy:babylon:
:trauma:
:triggered:
:truama:leadership:business:toxicity:
:unfurling:
:tagOne:tagTwo:etcTag:
```

And the **objective** is to get that into a list of single `:tag:`'s.

Again, the **problem** is that if a line has multiple tags, the line does not appear in the output at all (as opposed to the problem merely being that only the first tag of the line gets displayed).  Obviously the `| sed... |` there is problematic.

**I want `:tagOne:tagTwo:etcTag:` to be turned this into:

```
:tagOne:
:tagTwo:
:etcTag:
```

and so forth with `:politics:violence:` etc.

*Colons* aren't necessary, `tagOne` is just as good (maybe better, but this is trivial) than `:tagOne:`.

The **problem** is that if a line has multiple tags, the line does not appear in the output at all (as opposed to the problem merely being that only the first tag of the line gets displayed).  Obviously the `| sed... |` there is problematic.

So I should replace the `sed` with something better...

**I've tried**:

A smarter sed:

```
grep -rh -e '^:\S*:$' ~/Documents/wiki/*.mkd ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd | \
  sed -r 's|(:[Aa-Zz]*:)([Aa-Zz]*:)|\1\r:\2|g' | \
  sed -r 's|(:[Aa-Zz]*:)([Aa-Zz]*:)|\1\r:\2|g' | \
  sed -r 's|(:[Aa-Zz]*:)([Aa-Zz]*:)|\1\r:\2|g' | \
  sort -u
```

...which works (for a limited number of tags) except that it produces weird results like:

```
:toxicity:p:
:somewhat:y:
:people:n:
```

...placing weird random letters at the end of some tags in which `:p:` is the final character of the `:leadership:` tag and "leadership" no longer appears in the list.  Same for `:y:` and `:n:`.

I've also tried using loops in a couple ways...

```
grep -rh -e '^:\S*:$' ~/Documents/wiki/*.mkd ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd | \
  sed -r 's|(:[Aa-Zz]*:)([Aa-Zz]*:)|\1\r:\2|g' | \
  sed -r 's|(:[Aa-Zz]*:)([Aa-Zz]*:)|\1\r:\2|g' | \
  sed -r 's|(:[Aa-Zz]*:)([Aa-Zz]*:)|\1\r:\2|g' | \
  sort -u | grep lead
```

...which has the same problem of `:leadership:` tags being lost etc.
And like...

```
for m in $(grep -rh -e '^:\S*:$' ~/Documents/wiki/*.mkd ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd); do
  for t in $(echo $m | grep -e ':[Aa-Zz]*:'); do
    printf "$t\n";
  done
done | sort -u
```

...which doesn't separate the tags at all, just prints stuff like:
`:truama:leadership:business:toxicity`

Should I be taking some other approach?  Using a different utility (perhaps `cut` inside a loop)?  Maybe doing this in python (I have a few python scripts but don't know the language well, but maybe this would be easy to do that way)?  Every time I see `awk` I think "EEK!" so I'd prefer a non-awk solution please, preferring to stick to paradigms I've used in order to learn them better.

Comment: you've provided some sample outputs (what you want; what your script generates), but you haven't provided the any sample inputs; please update the question with the sample input that correspond with your outputs

Comment: ok, some sample input provided thanks :)

Comment: getting closer but ... there are 12 lines of sample input, but your outputs (current, expected)  don't match with these 12 lines, eg,  `tagOne`, `tagTwo`, `etcTag` and `people` show up in your outputs but not the input; it would help if the question was updated so the outputs (current, expected) correspond with those 12 lines of sample input; as noted in [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you need to provide us with the details necessary to reproduce the issue as well as a solution

Comment: ok, think it all makes sense now :)

Comment: eeek! what's with all the awk answers?!!!

Comment: all the awk answers are because awk is the right tool for the job. grep is for doing `g/re/p`, sed is for doing simple `s/old/new/` and for anything else you have awk. Not sure what the `eek!` is all about since awk is a tiny, simple C-like language. Trying to avoid awk when writing shell scripts is like being in construction and trying to avoid using a hammer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pipe through `tr` can split those strings out to separate lines:

```
grep -hx -- ':[:[:alnum:]]*:' ~/Documents/wiki{,/diary}/*.mkd | tr -s ':' '\n'
```

This will also remove the colons and an empty line will be present in the output (easy to repair, note the empty line will always be the first one due to the leading `:`). Add `sort -u` to sort and remove duplicates, or `awk '!seen[$0]++'` to remove duplicates without sorting.

An approach with `sed`:

```
sed '/^:/!d;s///;/:$/!d;s///;y/:/\n/' ~/Documents/wiki{,/diary}/*.mkd
```

This also removes colons, but avoids adding empty lines (by removing the leading/trailing `:` with `s` before using `y` to transliterate remaining `:` to `<newline>`). sed could be combined with tr:

```
sed '/:$/!d;/^:/!d;s///' ~/Documents/wiki{,/diary}/*.mkd | tr -s ':' '\n'
```

Using `awk` to work with the `:` separated fields, removing duplicates:

```
awk -F: '/^:/ && /:$/ {for (i=2; i<NF; ++i) if (!seen[$i]++) print $i}' \
~/Documents/wiki{,/diary}/*.mkd
```

Comment: Great contribution, I love this simplicity.  Converting the in-between `:` into a newline is precisely the simplicity I knew must exist!!!  This gives me: `grep -rh -e '^:\S*:$' ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd | tr -s ':' '\n' | sort -u` as a simple one-liner without the indecipherable PCRE and positive-lookbehind from the `...grep -Po...` answer (and a rabit-hole of learning that I didn't want to venture down alone).  So thank you :)

Comment: Do you have any idea why I can do `grep... *.mkd | tr -s ':' '\n' | sort -u` but not `grep ...*.mkd | sed 's|:|\r|g' | sort -u`?  That looks completely interchangeable to me, that `tr` and that `sed` but the `sed` breaks.  Making that change resulted in the same kind of weird breakage/problems that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @alec Glad to help. `tr -s` provides special handling of repeated characters ("squeezes" them into a single char, after any transliteration).

Comment: hmmm.... I don't follow... would you mind elaborating?

Comment: The problem is that `sed` is mysteriously removing a bunch of characters.  So I'm not sure how `tr` "squeezing" repeated characters would pertain here.  What repeated characters are you referring to, the `:`'s?  I'm confused how that relates to the problem that `sed` has of mistakenly removing characters.

Comment: @alec That sed command is using `\r` instead of `\n`. `sed 's|:|\n|g'` would work, but result in extra blank lines in output.

Comment: omg!  that's it!  Thank you!  No wonder `sed` has been behaving so mysteriously!!!  I think I've been confused by `vim`'s syntax for inserting a new line :/

Comment: This is the best solution, the `| tr -s ':' '\n'` is the simplest approach and you picked out the needle-in-the-haystack problem that noone noticed in my original question here with `sed`'s `\r` vs `\n`.  Yes :)

Answer (score 4):

Using PCRE in `grep` (where available) and *positive lookbehind*:

```
$ echo :tagOne:tagTwo:tagThree: |  grep -Po "(?<=:)[^:]+:"
tagOne:
tagTwo:
tagThree:
```

You will lose the leading : but get the tags nevertheless.

**Edit**: Did someone mention awk?:

```
$ awk '{
    while(match($0,/:[^:]+:/)) {
        a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+1)
    }
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i
}' file
```

Comment: Can you explain why the `-P` to use perl style regex is needed instead of just `-e`?

Comment: `man grep`: _-P - - Interpret PATTERNS as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs)_

Comment: _The purpose of `-e` is really just to disambiguate when a regex starts with a dash._

Answer (score 4):

Another idea using `awk` ...

Sample data generated by OPs initial `grep`:

```
$ cat tags.raw
:politics:violence:
:positivity:
:positivity:somewhat:
:psychology:
:socialServices:family:
:strategy:
:tech:
:therapy:babylon:
:trauma:
:triggered:
:truama:leadership:business:toxicity:
:unfurling:
:tagOne:tagTwo:etcTag:
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
    { split($0,tmp,":")                     # split input on colon;
                                            # NOTE: fields #1 and #NF are the empty string - see END block
      for ( x in tmp )                      # loop through tmp[] indices
          { arr[tmp[x]] }                   # store tmp[] values as  arr[] indices; this eliminates duplicates
    }
END { delete arr[""]                        # remove the empty string from arr[]
      for ( i in arr )                      # loop through arr[] indices
          { printf ":%s:\n", i }            # print each tag on separate line leading/trailing colons
    }
' tags.raw | sort                           # sort final output
```

**NOTE**: I'm not up to speed on `awk's` ability to internally sort arrays (thus eliminating the external `sort` call) so open to suggestions (or someone can copy this answer to a new one and update with said ability?)

The above also generates:

```
:babylon:
:business:
:etcTag:
:family:
:leadership:
:politics:
:positivity:
:psychology:
:socialServices:
:somewhat:
:strategy:
:tagOne:
:tagTwo:
:tech:
:therapy:
:toxicity:
:trauma:
:triggered:
:truama:
:unfurling:
:violence:
```

Answer (score 3):

Sample data generated by OPs initial `grep`:

```
$ cat tags.raw
:politics:violence:
:positivity:
:positivity:somewhat:
:psychology:
:socialServices:family:
:strategy:
:tech:
:therapy:babylon:
:trauma:
:triggered:
:truama:leadership:business:toxicity:
:unfurling:
:tagOne:tagTwo:etcTag:
```

One `while/for/printf` idea based on associative arrays:

```
unset arr
typeset -A arr                          # declare array named 'arr' as associative

while read -r line                      # for each line from tags.raw ...
do
    for word in ${line//:/ }            # replace ":" with space and process each 'word' separately
    do
        arr[${word}]=1                  # create/overwrite arr[$word] with value 1;
                                        # objective is to make sure we have a single entry in arr[] for $word;
                                        # this eliminates duplicates
    done
done < tags.raw

printf ":%s:\n" "${!arr[@]}" | sort     # pass array indices (ie, our unique list of words) to printf;
                                        # per OPs desired output we'll bracket each word with a pair of ':';
                                        # then sort
```

Per OPs comment/question about removing the array, a twist on the above where we eliminate the array in favor of printing from the internal loop and then piping everything to `sort -u`:

```
while read -r line                      # for each line from tags.raw ...
do
    for word in ${line//:/ }            # replace ":" with space and process each 'word' separately
    do
        printf ":%s:\n" "${word}"       # print ${word} to stdout
    done
done < tags.raw | sort -u               # pipe all output (ie, list of ${word}s for sorting and removing dups
```

Both of the above generates:

```
:babylon:
:business:
:etcTag:
:family:
:leadership:
:politics:
:positivity:
:psychology:
:socialServices:
:somewhat:
:strategy:
:tagOne:
:tagTwo:
:tech:
:therapy:
:toxicity:
:trauma:
:triggered:
:truama:
:unfurling:
:violence:
```

Comment: Is the array necessary?  I love seeing a loop example, thanks.  Would it be possible to simply print the `word` on its own line inside the for loop?  (`sort -u` could make sure they're unique)

Comment: yeah, that's doable; the only reason I added the array (which automatically removed dups) is that I have no idea what you plan on doing with the data downstream, ie, while the Q&A asks to just display the unique list, it doesn't say what you plan on doing with the list (eg, do you need to use this list for follow-on processing) so the array gives you a set of data you can 're-use' later without having to reprocess the raw data; give me a min and I'll add another section that eliminates the array in favor of `print/sort` ...

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to substitue `< tags.raw` for `< command`?  In this case the command would be `grep -rh -e '^:\S*:$' ~/Documents/wiki/*.mkd ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd` but when I do that I get `syntax error near unexpected token `-rh'`.

Comment: @alec yes, the intent would be to replace `tags.raw` with your command, but you need the correct format; you want to go from `done < tags.raw` to `done < <(command)` (that's `done` + `<space>` + `<` + `<space>` + `<(command)`

Comment: another alternative would be to pipe the output from your `grep` into the `while` loop, eg: `grep ... | while read -r line; do ... printf ... ; done; done` (notice the outer `done` has nothing after it because the input data is coming in from stdin via the pipe); though keep in mind if you go this route that any variables (including arrays) you may set within the `while` loop will disappear upon exiting the `while` loop ... because the `while` loop is actually invoked in a sub-shell and local variable/array assignments are not passed to the parent process upon leaving the sub-shell ...

Comment: Yes, that's the option I like best!  Thanks!

Comment: ... but anything coming out of that sub-shell/`while` loop that ends up going to stdout (eg, `printf` output) will still show up in the console

Comment: one correction on the `grep ... | while ... done; done` idea ... you'll still need the `| sort -u` on the very end of that, so ... `grep ... | while ... done; done | sort -u`

Comment: for the parent loop... what are the implications/reasons of using `while` instead of `for`???

Comment: extra sub-process, eg: ... `for i in $(<command>); do ... ; done` ... or ... `<command> | for i in ${cat}; do ... ; done` ... also need to decide if the data you're processing has white space and how you intend to process said data; run a google search on `bash while vs for` and review the answers, like [this answer: while vs for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24278)